# how can i get the result of JavaScript function of another websites page in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I've application that uses another web sites data so how can i get it because it uses some JavaScript functions to get that data and it not show in page view-source.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? You'd have to link to there JS files but it could be dynamic content.

Comment: Are you scraping them with their consent? If so: how do they *tell* you to get the data?

Comment: Some more info on the exact scenario might help getting some specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the NET tab in firebug, XHR and check the resource that is requested, and request the same resource.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to render the webpage and ensure the javascript functions are run (evaluated). You could do this by "borrowing" their javascript files (by linking to them from your own page), but this may not work as you don't know what's in those files - they could be accessing DOM elements that you don't have in your page, or calling to other domains which may prevent them from working correctly.

The easiest way to show the same data is to just host the page inside an iframe on your own page. If you are looking to do this from a normal client application (i.e. not a web app) then you will need a browser control that you navigate to the target page. If the browser control is invisible you could then scrape values from it and show them in your app, although this is a very clumsy way to do it, and it's debatable about how ethical it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the another web site view source use the HTTPWebRequest to get the response stream in c#.